# get current page from url

Tags: c#, url, request

I want to write a c# method to retrieve the current page. eg Default6.aspx I know I can do the following:

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
// http://localhost:1302/TESTERS/Default6.aspx

string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
// /TESTERS/Default6.aspx

string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
// localhost
```

but how can I get Default6.aspx? And if the url is http://localhost:1302/TESTERS/, my method should return default.aspx

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
Path.GetFileName( Request.Url.AbsolutePath )
```

Comment: Think that should be 'Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath)'

Comment: What if i have '#' in URL.....                                                                       i.e :http:test.abc.com/sitesposure.aspx#commentfocus.........                   will it work?

Comment: @PPB depends on what you mean by "work". The internal anchor name (= all text starting at #) WON'T be transmitted to the server. So you won't see it and won't be able to process it.

Answer (score 12):

The class you need is **`System.Uri`**

```
Dim url As System.Uri = Request.UrlReferrer 
Debug.WriteLine(url.AbsoluteUri)   ' => http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx
Debug.WriteLine(url.AbsolutePath)  ' => /default.aspx
Debug.WriteLine(url.Host)          ' => http:/www.mysite.com
Debug.WriteLine(url.Port)          ' => 80
Debug.WriteLine(url.IsLoopback)    ' => False
```

http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18709

Comment: OP probably already knew about this reference. You failed to address the question which is : why is there tons of (useless)  properties and none for the page name (=las segment) which is the one that matters the most.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("/");
```

Comment: BTW, this will return "/MyPage.aspx". Also, for VB.Net users you might try `Request.Path.Substring(Request.Path.LastIndexOf("/"))`

Answer (score 5):

A simple function like below will help :

```
public string GetCurrentPageName() 
{ 
    string sPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath; 
    System.IO.FileInfo oInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(sPath); 
    string sRet = oInfo.Name; 
    return sRet; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this below.

```
string url = "http://localhost:1302/TESTERS/Default6.aspx";

string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(url);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
Request.Url.Segments.Last()
```

Another option.

Comment: this is not a good way. example:  www.mysite.com/Product/3.  The name of the page maybe Product or even Details or Index.  Your statement would return 3. Not the name of the page or even what correct argument from the url.

Comment: If you are using any URL rewriting, I definitely agree that it is not useful.  However, if you are using URL rewriting such as your example, what would be the equivalent of the Default6.aspx in the question?