# String Parsing using C#

Tags: c#, string

I'm very beginner in C# and I would like to only extract the `"title"` string from a string like that: `"http://playdebug.games.com/facebook/title.html"`

Comment: Guys. The man just gave an example for getting the _title_ section of an URL. What you look for is **[HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830763/get-current-page-from-url)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest going with [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
String toParse = "http://playdebug.games.com/facebook/title.html";
String result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(toParse);
```

Comment: I think `Path` allows for file system paths only, not URIs.

Comment: @OndrejTucny No, it works just fine enough for URIs also.

Answer (score 0):

just get the last part via substring, position to cut is the last index of '/'. 
string s = "http://playdebug.games.com/facebook/title.html";

```
 s = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

or the short way since it can be treated as a path ;)

```
 string s = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("http://playdebug.games.com/facebook/title.html");
```