# Get url Address from current page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a c# code and need to get full URL address from current page.
In method I have :

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

but there is error. HttpContext does not exist in the current context

i have dll (using System.Web;)
second try was:

```
string url = Request.Url.Host;
```

but error on Request does not exist.

how can get URL address ? 
my main question is. why i got error on HttpContext   or Request.Url.Host ?

Comment: Read this. [get current page from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830763/get-current-page-from-url)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current URL from ASP.NET code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785885/how-to-get-the-current-url-from-asp-net-code-behind)

Comment: Do you see that he is saying HttpContext.Current=null?

Comment: Do you show the code where do you want to do get it ?

Comment: firstly i want to get URL
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
label.text = url;
but i have error  on HttpContext.Current. also wich class must have?  using System.web  have.

Comment: @refreshg I think you are trying to get the URL in a class library or something and not in the code-behind file. You cannot access HttpContext or Request outside code-behind file.

Comment: @Bharat Gupta   i have a private void method. and in this method must get url. is it possible?

Comment: Is the method inside the code-behind file? Is the method non-static?

Comment: HttpContext.Current should do the trick. Please show us where you are calling this to identify why it is not working. You should call it on a thread that has http context and not some background thread that has none.

Comment: @Bharat Gupta   Here is full code >> https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PaieTxK3VUW2Vr5CFV1vbuuEb7I_iElblR76C_btFjc/edit?usp=sharing
see getadress method

Comment: What is this **Context** in EleWise.ELMA.Workflow.Scripts.ProcessScriptBase<Context>? I mean, what parameter are using in **Context** placeholder while creating the object of EleWise.ELMA.Workflow.Scripts.ProcessScriptBase<Context>?

Comment: i use BMPN 2.0 leanguge and in this c#.  Context in EleWise.ELMA.Workflow.Scripts.ProcessScriptBase<Context>   this is for BPMN

Comment: I am afraid, getadress will not work in this context. You can however pass the address from the code-behind (aspx.cs) while calling this getadress method.

Comment: thanks. i will try

Comment: @BharatGupta Yes, you can use HttpContext.Current in a class library or non-code behind context. The requirement is that you still must be in a web context - the code must be executing in response to a user request.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Will try that out.